# my mvc application is getting logout after some time [30m] of inactivity and when I click on any link of site

Tags: saml-2.0, logout

my mvc application is getting logout after some time [30m] of inactivity and when I click on any link of site.

when i checked Request.IsAuthenticated is comming as false.

i am using pingidentity as saml2.

Comment: when Request.Isauthenticated gets false.?

Comment: What SAML stack are you using? Can you check if the SAML response contains a `SessionNotOnOrAfter` value?